# Does my method work for finding each word in a string

Tags: java

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make a method that will individually work on each word of a string. I've gotten the code down but I'm not sure if it is right. So I ran a couple of tests to see if it prints out appropriately. After multiple tries and absolutely nothing printing out. I need help. Can anyone find anything wrong my code?

```
public static String build( String str4, one test){
     Scanner find = new Scanner( System.in);
     String phrase = " ";
     while ( find.hasNext()){
         String word = find.next();
         word = test.change(word);
         phrase += word + " ";

     }
     return phrase;
}
```

The method change just changes the word to pig latin ( my intended goal ).

Here are the simple lines in my main method:

```
 String str4 = "I am fluent in pig latin";
    System.out.println (test.build(str4, test));
```

I intended for this code to print out this:

Iyay amyay uentflay inyay igPay atinLay

Comment: Well, you don't have any print statements.  What makes you think this code *should* print anything?

Comment: I didnt post the code for the checking since I assumed that is how you check... I will edit

Comment: please include sample input and expected output as well

Comment: Sorry I'm newish here, could you elaborate or be more specific? Expected output just want i want it to return but input?

Comment: @JackNguyen what is class  one/

Comment: name of my class. So I created an object of it in order to call methods

Comment: What does the `change()` method in the `one` class do?  If it's not returning what you think, the posted code will just string empty spaces together.

Comment: @azurefrog The posted code won't do anything, including print empty spaces, because, as it is currently written, `find.next()` is just waiting for console input...

Comment: @JasonC Ah, you're right.  It won't even do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
Scanner find = new Scanner( System.in);
```

Which means you're reading from user input.

You also have this `str4` parameter, but you're not actually using it. You seem to have inadvertently used `System.in` as your input string source when you really meant to use your `str4` parameter. Hence, nothing happens, as `find.next()` is waiting for input from the console rather than using the string you passed in.

You probably mean:

```
Scanner find = new Scanner(str4);
```

Comment: I see, I understand this completely. Recently I had only used scanner asking for user input for something like a chatting bot. But this was the first time I tried to use it in another fashion. So changing it to str4 input makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4):

You attempt to get some input inside your function, using the `Scanner` instance, giving user input as its construction argument.

In order to print what is going to be returned, add this line:

```
System.out.println (phrase);
```

before your return statement.

What I am guessing though, is you are mistakenly using user input.
Try this instead:

```
public static String build( String str4, one test){
 Scanner find = new Scanner(str4);
 String phrase = " ";
 while ( find.hasNext()){
     String word = find.next();
     word = test.change(word);
     phrase += word + " ";
 }
 //Print your phrase here if you want.
 System.out.println(phrase);
 return phrase;
```

}

Comment: You are right, this note was useful, thanks, and thanks for the bravery to help a similar answer to yours, really appreciated.

Comment: Perfect. I managed to narrow it down to the code not even getting to the loop so I figured it had to be something with the while long which uses the scanner object I created. Str4 makes a lot of sense. Thanks.